# Is it safe to use foo() && 0 in C?

Tags: c

Imagine i have the following piece of C-code where foo() produces a side effect and returns an integer:

```
if(bar) {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, say I really like making my code compact, possibly at the reader's expense, and I change it into this:

```
if (bar)
    return foo() && 0;
```

Can I be sure these two pieces of code will produce the same behavior, or would I risk the call to foo() not being executed due to possible compiler optimizations or something like that, thus not producing the desired side-effect?

**NOTE**: This is not a question about which piece of code is better, but whether the two pieces actually produce the same behavior in all cases. I think the majority (and I) can agree that the former piece of code should be used.

Comment: Why not `return foo(), 0;`? It's fewer characters and matches your intent better.

Comment: I changed it to be nested into an if, thus making the "argument" for compact code stronger. I like your answer, however, I don't think it applies to the new version. :-/

Comment: Looking at the history, I don't see any material changes to your code. Why don't you think it applies to your current version?

Comment: My bad. I guess I didn't read your first comment thoroughly enough, and also wasn't aware of how the ","  works. You're completely right, just as the accepted answer explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two forms you give are equivalent. The C11 standard (draft n1570) states,

```
6.5.13 Logical AND operator
...
Semantics

3 The && operator shall yield 1 if both of its operands compare unequal to 0;
  otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.
4 Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees left-to-right
  evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between
  the evaluations of the first and second operands. If the first operand compares
  equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.
```

Similar language appeared in all C standards so far.

You should probably prefer using the comma operator here (`return foo(), 0;`) because:

- It's shorter (one character versus two for the operator, and you can get away with removing the left space character when using a comma, for a total of two fewer characters).
- It gives you more flexibility, as you can return non-scalar types (such as structs), and a wider range of integers than just 0 or 1.
- It conveys the intent better: "Discard return value of `foo()` and return something else (`0`) instead".

Now if you do chance upon a compiler that deletes the call to `foo()`, then either the compiler managed to prove that `foo()` is a function with no visible side-effects, or more likely it has a serious bug and you should report it.

Comment: Very thorough and useful answer. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, those two are the same.  `foo()` will always be called (assuming `bar` is true).

Comment: Nope.  Depending upon `foo()`'s return type, the second code snippet may not even compile.

Comment: It might be helpful to specify which operators are guaranteed to evaluate expressions from left to right,  i.e. (`&&`, `||`, `?:`, and `,`).

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps, that's possible, I guess.  I was assuming OP's code compiled in both cases.

Comment: It can be assumed that foo returns an integer. I have updated my question to reflect that. :-)

Comment: @CarlNorum: How can you be sure that foo() will always be executed. What if some compile-time optimization reduced the statement to simply "return 0;"? Wouldn't that be a possibility?

Comment: @Phazyck, no it's not a possibility.  The semantics of the `&&` operator forbid it.

Comment: Do you have some sources I can read through? I'd kinda like to know the whole story. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why obfuscate your code in the latter?

Use the former.

Easier to read i.e. this is easier to understand

```
if(bar) {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Or unless got a problem with job security

Comment: So I don't need to use brackets for my if-statement. I'm well aware the former is better, however, that is besides the question. The question is whether or not these will actually always produce the same outcome. :-)

Comment: @Phazyck: At some point in your education you realize that squeezing as much code as possible into a single line is dumb and only makes your code harder to understand.

Comment: I'm completely aware of that, don't worry. :-)

Comment: @Phazyck - The outcome (in the bigger picture) is to write code that is easy to understand and read. Hence maintain. Hence easier for some unfortunate person to fix when a certain substance hits that wind instrument.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, it does not answer my question. :-)

Comment: @Phazyck - |Try it. They probably do the same but would I employ a programmer that write such code in the former. Me thinks not as it will be difficult to maintain

Comment: Never said I would prefer to write the latter. ;-)